# Graph API Explorer, returning different result

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to FQL query comments, made by my on photo's my friends were tagged in.

```
SELECT text FROM comment WHERE object_id IN ( SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE
subject IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me()) ) AND fromid=me() LIMIT 1000
```

The query in it self works fine on the Graph API Explorer. When i am on the Graph API Explorer, and then choose my app to run the query the result comes up empty, were the Graph API App returns results.

Any ideas on this? I have noted that other people have had this issue. But there seems to be no fix for it? I am wondering if people just gave up. Because i have also been at it for a while without any solutions.

I will limit the query, so it dosen't look back more than 3 months, but for now it's not so i am sure i get some data.

Comment: Have you given your own app different permissions than the Graph Explorer app?

Comment: Nope. Same permissions. It seems a lot of people are having the issue. I found a bug report on facebook with another guy having similar issues with different results it was a known issue they wont be fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we found the issue ourselves, while the Graph API Explorer (the tool) follows the documentation that facebook provides, your own implementation does not. So it's consistently different, so we were able to make it work knowing this, so with what should actually be an bug we made it work.

Comment: And could you say how you fixed this? I'm getting the same behavior.

Comment: We had to take another approach SELECT col, col2 FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() - When using your own app as testing enviroment on the Graph Tool Explorer returns your activity feed not wall of the user. source_id (The ID of the user, page, group, or event whose wall the post is on) it says on facebook but it's incorrect. And then we did loop through the activity feed to get comments and so on, note that comments only return an excerpt of the comment not the full. :S But a wall post or status does.